# who received message posted by me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I implemented actioncable for real time messaging, Now I want to know who received the message posted by me. all users are communicating using the same channel

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_channel"
  end

  def speak(data)
    Message.create_message(data, current_user)
  end
end
```

Exact idea is described in attached image, this will perform while I reload the page, but I want to distinguish on action of receive message.[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to receive an email when a message is received that has the name of the user who sent the message?  Or you want to receive a live notification?

Comment: Yes, Any information of user who posted message

Comment: does your message model have a user id?

Comment: Yes message model have a user id

Comment: if your message model is named message, for example, when it's received couldn't you just use @message.user_id to find the sender?  ie User.find(@message.user_id)

Comment: And how to find I am login with which user id something like `<% if current_user == message.user %>`

But when I broadcast message all user will recieve same data.

Comment: @RyanMurphy I edited the question

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do.  What is the context?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial has both a chat room implementation and a one to one implementation of chatting using action cable. Its the best tutorial out there to start with action cable. Go here `https://www.learnenough.com/action-cable-tutorial`.